# Use $(this) in an outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and I wonder why it's not working for me:

```
function resetColor(){
     $(this).css( { "color": "red" } )
}

$('.class').click(function() {
     resetColor();
});
```

I also tried to save `$(this)` as a variable when clicking the `.class`, but that didn't work for me also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` represents the context of who called the function. When you call `resetColor`, it's implicitly using the top level `this` which is the `window` object. If you would like maintain context to through function calls, you can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    resetColor.call(this);
});
```

The other obvious option is to not use `this`, but rather pass the element as an argument.

```
function resetColor(e) {
     $(e).css({color: 'red'});
}

$('.class').click(function() {
     resetColor(this);
});
```

Answer (score 11):

A simpler way is to reference the function instead of wrapping it inside an anonymous one, like this:

```
$('.class').click(resetColor);
```

Answer (score 5):

best way to it is to pass it as argument

```
function resetColor(element) {
     $(element).css( { "color": "red" } )
}

$('.class').click(function() {
     resetColor(this);
});
```

another way it to define resetColor as function inside the object

```
    jQuery.fn.resetColor = function() {
         $(this).css( { "color": "red" } )
    }
    $('.class').click(function() {
         $(this).resetColor();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a special variable in Javascript, it contains the *context* of the function call. When you call a property of an object in the form `object.function()`, `this` gets the value of the object. If you don't call the function that way, `this` defaults to the `window` object. Since you're not calling a property, the latter happens.

The simple way to solve your problem is to pass the the element as an argument.

```
function resetColor(element) {
    element.css({ color: "red" });
}

$(".class").click(function() {
    resetColor($(this));
};
```

Another way is to bind the event directly to the function:

```
$(".class").click(resetColor);
```

Or you can do what jQuery does internally, which is to use `.apply` or `.call`, which allows specifying the context explicitly:

```
$(".class").click(function() {
    resetColor.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` in javascript refers to the current instance of an object (as in other languages) and is an auto variable. It's of course not available outside an object context.

jQueries `$` is a global object, build in a way that `this` is always the current DOM reference. That's a basic concept behind jQuery.

To solve the above problem, check out this code:

```
function resetColor(that){
     $(that).css( { "color": "red" } )
}

$('.class').click(function() {
     resetColor(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function resetColor(classname){
 $(classname).css('color', 'red');
 }

 $('.class').click(function() {
 resetColor(this);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eayx/ecLq37ey/

or add the function to click.

```
$('.class').click(function() {
     $(this).css( { "color": "red" } )
});
```